# AsyncTask not working - cannot instantiate the type error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a `public class FriendMaps extends MapActivity` that gets called from a menu item when selected, and at the end of that I have `private abstract class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` in there I do some server calls and put data into local arrays etc.

But in my `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the FriendMaps activity I call `new DownloadFilesTask().execute();` and get the following error:

> Error: Cannot instantiate the type
>   FriendMaps.DownloadFilesTask

From the documentation:

> AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used.

That would be accomplished  `DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask` there.

> The task instance must be created on the UI thread

Maybe this is where I am confused?  To my understanding the UI thread is the current activity being displayed - if so then the onCreate of the FriendMaps activity is the correct place to execute();

If full code spinets are required for further help, please comment and I'll add where needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't instantiate it because you declared `DownloadFilesTask` as an abstract class, that, by definition, cannot be instantiated

Comment: thanks, don't know why I had abstract in there.  Now I have to figure out why the AsyncTask is crashing my map :/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make your declaration like this

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

You probably didn't mean it to be an abstract class, and as @maid450 said, you can't instantiate an abstract class.